# Min and Max are not working as expected on input='time'

Tags: html, dom, input, time

I am a little bit confused about how the `min` and `max` attributes work, when `<input type="time"/>` is set. With this [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#try_it)

```html
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" min="09:00" max="18:00" required>
```

I would expect a time before `9:00` and and after `18:00` to not be selectable. But it is. You can try that on the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#try_it). I tested it on Chrome, FireFox and Edge.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you can hover over input after selecting wrong time. A title display warning for you

Comment: for this situation, i request create js code to validate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in form validation takes place when the form is submitted (i.e. when the submit button is clicked) or when [`reportValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) is called.

It doesn't prevent invalid data being entered in the first place. It just catches it before it is sent to the server.

This screenshot shows the output in Firefox:

[image: Form with the message "Please select a value that is no earlier than 09:00"]

```js
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('form').reportValidity(), 50);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" min="09:00" max="18:00" required value="08:00">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```